# Preserving a task after leaving the view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, persist

I have a view controller where I initiate two tasks. One for fetching location updates and another for getting accelerometer and gyro sensor data updates. I have separated the inner workings of these two to two separate classes and I retrieve the data form the view controller via delegates.

I'm faced with an issue. Say, I initiate location and motion sensor data fetching in the view controller and then I leave the said view controller. This in turn destroys the objects created over there and when I return to the view controller, it's all reset.

I want those initiated operations to remain active even when I leave the view controller. And persist until I come back. How do I handle a situation like this?

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to go about this. You could make the class that performs these functions a singleton that never gets destroyed and any of your classes can get access to. Another option, which is not as good IMO, would be to pass the object from the first view controller to the second view controller.

Answer (score 0):

Singletons could be a solution for this. Check this [post](https://thatthinginswift.com/singletons/)
This way as long as you start a manager it will stay alive irrespective of the view controller state.

Answer (score 0):

While coming back from the 2nd view controller, you shouldn't initiate your first view controller(Where you are initiating location and motion sensor data). This can be done in two ways.

- One is using navigation controller pushing your second view controller and coming back
- Presenting 2nd view controller from the existing view controller and dismissing 2nd view controller while coming back

**Other way:** (If instantiating your first view controller)

Declaring location & motion sensor data variables globally in appdelegate and assigning values to them in your first view controller. Doing these you can use these values anywhere.